# How to get indexes where two arrays are equal?

Tags: matlab

I have two large arrays

`t = 0: 5e-4 : 1`

`f = @(t) some function`

They are too big for a certain analysis, so instead I would like to sample from each of them so that the sampled array would look like

`t_sampled = 0:5e-2:1`

I would like to accomplish this by getting the index where `t==t_sampled`.
This way, I can just say that `t_sampled = t(idx)`

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just pass `t_sampled` directly into `f`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to find for each element of `t_sampled` the index `k` into `t` where `t[ii] - t_sampled[k]` is minimal. If the arrays were unordered, you'd have to be general and compare all elements:

```
[~, idx] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, t', t_sampled)));
```

However since `t` is strictly monotonous, you can simply use [`interp1`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) on the indices `1:numel(t)`:

```
idx = interp1(t, 1:numel(t), t_sampled, 'nearest');
```

or even directly on the desired values:

```
f_sampled = interp1(t, ft, t_sampled, 'nearest');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but seems it like `datasample` will give the solution:

```
t = 0:5e-4:1;
p = 0.01;       % the proportion of t to sample [0..1)
t_sampled = datasample([t; 1:length(t)].',floor(length(t)*p),'Replace',false);
t_ind = t_sampled(:,2)
```

now, `t_ind` will be the index of the sampled `t`.

there is another, simpler option without `datasample`:

```
t_ind = (randperm(length(t),floor(length(t)*p))) % indecies
t_sampled = t(t_ind) % values that was sampled
```

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: If you use toolbox functions in your answer you should probably tell people up front.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know it's a toolbox one, when you have them installed you don't really see where in comes from, and there no point in remember it in real life (i.e. outside SO). I'll add an answer without tool box functions.

Comment: I didn't know there was a life outside of SO, please tell me more!